# InstallShield broke TFS Build

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs, tfsbuild, azure-devops

I am getting this error when using VisualStudio.com to build my solution:

```
C:\a\src\...\Setup\Setup.isproj (30): The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\InstallShield\2013Limited\InstallShield.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
```

One of the projects in my solution is an InstallShield installer project. Am I supposed to remove it? Or is there a way to make it work with TFS Build on the cloud?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

InstallShield is not installed on the Hosted Build Services, so you'll have to disable the project for VSO. You don't have to remove it, it's enough to create a new build configuration and untick the "build" option. Then configure the Build to use the "BuildServer|AnyCpu" configuration to build.

[image]
[image]

If you want to build your project including the installer, you'll need to install your own build agent/controller and install InstallShield on that. Either on an Azure VM or on an on-premise

Comment: Hi. I am getting same issue. Can you explain exactly how do I disable the project for VSO in Visual Studio 2015, 2017 ? Thanks.

Comment: @DheerajKumar I added images for better clarity